# Type mismatch VSFlexGrid VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a problem like this

```
 If EditData = False Then
        'Simpan data
        If Grd_StatUjian.TextMatrix(Grd_StatUjian.RowSel, 2) > 30 Then
        MsgBox "Sesi Tersebut Sudah Penuh... Silahkan Cari Sesi Lainnya...!", vbInformation, "Informasi"
        Else
       cn.Execute "INSERT INTO ujian_mhs VALUES ('" & 0 & "','" & TBox(0).Text & "','" & cb_sesi.Text & "','" & cb_hari.Text & "','" & TBox(3).Text & "','" & TBox(5).Text & "','" & cb_ujian.Text & "','" & frmBack.lbta.Caption & "')"
       End If
    Else
        'Update data
      cn.Execute "UPDATE ujian_mhs SET sesi_ujian='" & cb_sesi.Text & "',hari_ujian='" & cb_hari.Text & "',kd_instruktur='" & TBox(5).Text & "'" & _
                   "WHERE NPM='" & TBox(0).Text & "'"
    End If
```

It shows "Type mismatch", especially in the part of this code :

```
  If Grd_StatUjian.TextMatrix(Grd_StatUjian.RowSel, 2) > 30 Then
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`Grd_StatUjian.TextMatrix` returns the string and you are comparing integer with it. Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261271(v=vs.60).aspx).
Don't forget to add the check for string with non numeric data.

```
If CInt(Grd_StatUjian.TextMatrix(Grd_StatUjian.RowSel, 2)) > 30 Then
```